# Images appear like they are CMYK when uploaded to web. However, they are RGB

Tags: wordpress, image, image-processing, rgb, cmyk

I have worked with images/Photoshop for a long time and have never had this problem. Basically, I tried uploading a few images to WordPress and they appear like this:

[image]

As you can see, the one highlighted in green turns out fine. However, the other two for some reason come out looking like they are in CMYK mode. The images are RGB and saved for web so I'm not sure what the problem might be. Can anyone help me make sense of this?

Here is the file for one of the images that come out wrong (which is strange because it comes out fine here, maybe it's a strictly WordPress issue?):

[image]

Comment: When you say the colours are wrong, do you mean the slightly bluish cast to them?

Answer (score 0):

I think your comment about CMYK is a red herring. Looking at your screen shot, it appears you may have inadvertently selected the images in the window; your browser has highlighted them to show this, which gives them a slight blue overlay. Try simply reloading the page and opening that window again and see if the issue goes away.

Answer (score 0):

Ive had strange things happen from images that appeared ok in windows photo viewer but when loaded into adobe fireworks the colours go wrong in a similar way.

Im assuming that the pictures display incorrectly on the 'front end' of Wordpress too, therefore i think its some weird .jpg format issue.

If you have just a few images maybe worth manually screen grab and edit screen grab if you have a viewer that works, then save out and try to re-upload to wordpress.

Or batch process the files into a different format, say bump and use a wordpress plugin like insanity that has the option to automatically convert to .jpg, to in effect clean or at least change the image format on upload.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue- If you delete the image from wordpress, change the size of the image file to something closer to the size of the page width, that might work. It worked for me. I can't explain why that happens, but it does!